# PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "call")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Добрый день!

Проблема при сохранение данных в БД, код сущности :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class File implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "upload_time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date uploadTime;
    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;
    @Column(name = "size")
    private Long size;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String decription;
    @Transient
    private byte[] fileBody;
```

Код класса dao

```
    @EJB(name = "java:jboss/local/fileDao", beanInterface = FileDao.class)
@LocalBean
@Stateful
public class FileDao implements FileDaoLocal {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileDao.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPADB")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveFile(File file) {
        try {
            file.setPath("/opt/files/"+file.getName());
            file.setDecription("123321");
            file.setSize((long)file.getFileBody().length);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/files/"+file.getName());
            fos.write(file.getFileBody());
            fos.close();   

            em.persist(file);           
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Ошибка:

```
    16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:100)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:59)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:422)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
16:32:06,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    ... 262 more
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "call")
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)   Позиция: 1
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:616)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:466)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:351)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
16:32:06,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)    ... 274 more
```

persistance.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="JPADB">
    <jta-data-source>java:/db</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>ejb.entity.File</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `persistance.xml` попробуйте

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
```

вместо

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
```